# When calling ASP.NET Core 6 Web API, I get the error message 400 bad request

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-6.0

A little strange. If the following programs are all in the ASP.NET Core 6 MVC project, there will be no problem.

But if you separate the program. Ajax is in the ASP.NET Core 6 MVC project, and the C# function is in the ASP.NET Core 6 Web API project. When Ajax calls a C# function, I always get 400 bad request error.

How to solve this problem?

Javascript (Ajax):

```
    var data = {
        value1: "ProposerMail",
        value2: "ExpextMail",
    };

    var url = "https://localhost:7253/Values/api/Test666";
    
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',                   
        data: data,             
    }).done(function (data) {

        var lsTemp;
        lsTemp = "AAA";

    })
        .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

            alert(jqXHR.status);
            alert(textStatus);
            alert(errorThrown);

        });
```

C#:

```
   [HttpPost]
   [Route("api/Test666/")]
   public IActionResult Test666(string value1, string value2)
   {
      return Ok(value1);
   }
```

I can't find answers to related questions on the website, so I hope someone can provide advice to help solve the problem.

Comment: you should use a model class for the values. also is your request going to json or form data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to include the contentType in an Ajax request to specify the MIME-type (which will be sent in the [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header)

```
$.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",                   
        data: data,
        contentType: "application/json"

    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone's help, this problem has been solved

```
Js::

[HttpPost]
[Route("api/Test666")]
public IActionResult Test666([FromBody] MyModel model) // Use a model class
{
    return Ok(model.Value1); // Return the value1 property
}

public class MyModel
{
    public string Value1 { get; set; }
    public string Value2 { get; set; }
}

C#::
var lsTemp;
 lsTemp = "AAAA";

 var data = {
     value1: "ProposerMail",
     value2: "ExpextMail",
 };

 var url = "https://localhost:7253/Values/api/Test666"; // Remove "Values" from the route
 //https://localhost:7253/Values/api/Test666
 $.ajax({
     url: url,
     type: 'POST',
     contentType: 'application/json', // Set the content type
     data: JSON.stringify(data), // Serialize the data
 }).done(function (response) {
     var lsTemp = "AAA";
     console.log(response); // Log the response
 }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
     alert(jqXHR.status);
     alert(textStatus);
     alert(errorThrown);
 });
```